# Let $f: X \to Y$ be a homeomorphism and $A \subset X$. Show that $\overline{f(A)} = f(\overline{A})$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a homeomorphism and $A \subset X$. Show that $\overline{f(A)} = f(\overline{A})$.

In essence I want to show that two sets are the same so I should show that $\overline{f(A)} \subset f(\overline{A})$ and $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$?

I'm stuck on how I should go about this. If I let $x \in \overline{f(A)}$, then what properties of the homeomorphism can I use to show that $x \in f(\overline{A})$? Initially I assumed I could use continuity to say that if $f(x) \in f(\overline{A})$, then there exist $x \in \overline{A}$ and we have open neighborhoods $U_x$ and $V_{f(x)}$, but this doesn't seem to be helpful. Is there something else I should consider? $f$ is certainly bijective also since it's homeomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

To which it seems to me, it is enough that the function $f$ is continuous. For this case I see that it is more convenient to work with limits than with neighborhoods. Note that, as the $f$ function is continuous, we have the property: $$ \lim f(a_n) = f (\lim a_n) $$

1. $f(\overline{A})\subset\overline{f(A)}$

If $x\in f(\overline{A})$, then $x=f(a)$ with $a\in \overline{A}$. That is, $a=\lim a_n$ and $$x=f\left(\lim a_n\right)=\lim f(a_n) \Rightarrow x\in\overline{f(A)}$$

2. $\overline{f(A)}\subset f(\overline{A})$

Similarly, on the other hand, if $x\in \overline{f(A)}$, then $$ x=\lim f(a_n)=f(\lim a_n)=f(a_0) $$

where $a_0=\lim a_n$. Note that if $f(a_ n)$ diverges, then $a_ n$ also diverges, because $f$ is a continuous function. So, from 1 and 2 we have $\overline{f(A)} = f(\overline{A})$.

Answer (score 0):

Note $A \subseteq \overline{A}$ and thus $f(A) \subseteq f(\overline{A})$. Now take closure, $\overline{f(A)}\subseteq \overline{f(\overline{A})}$. But, $f(\overline{A})$ is closed by $f$ a homeomorphism, thus $\overline{f(\overline{A})}=f(\overline{A})$. Therefore, $\overline{f(A)}\subseteq f(\overline{A})$.

The harder direction is showing the other direction; however, it follows similarly.

Answer (score 0):

A map is continuous if and only if $f\left (\overline A\right ) \subseteq \overline {f(A)}$ for all subsets $A$ of the domain. If $f$ is a homeomorphism then $f^{-1}$ is defined and continuous, so $f^{-1}\left (\overline B\right ) \subseteq \overline {f^{-1}(B)}$ for all subsets $B$ of the codomain. Applying $f$ to the inclusion gives $\overline B = f\left (f^{-1}\left (\overline B\right ) \right) \subseteq f\left (\overline {f^{-1}(B)}\right )$, if we now take $B = f(A)$ we get the opposite inclusion $\overline {f(A)}\subseteq f\left (\overline A\right )$.